# Can disjoint classes in an ontology share the same data properties?

Tags: ontology, protege

I am currently writing my master's thesis on ontology-based knowledge bases in academic libraries. For this purpose, I am trying to model the domain knowledge of a specialised music library as an ontology into which the domain knowledge can later be transferred.
I use Protégé (version 5.6.1) as a tool for this. However, I think I lack a certain basic understanding in some points. **The question is whether disjoint classes can have common data properties.**

An example:
I have two classes: Library and Library Team.
The class "Library" has, among other things, the data property "Phone number", which refers to the general service telephone number. The class "Library team" has, among other things, the data properties "Last name" and "First name", both of which are individual for this class. At the same time, there is also the data property "Telephone number", but this time it refers to the individual telephone numbers of the team members.
The two classes are disjoint. This means that no individual of the Team member class can be an individual of the Library class at the same time. Nevertheless, the classes in my modelling currently share the Phone number property.

The question now is: Is this procedure permissible from an ontological point of view? Or would I have to model the "phone number" property separately for both classes?

I have used the two reasoners HermiT (version 1.4.3) and Pellet as a test, both of which issue an error when I create an individual of the "Library Team" class with the corresponding properties. I assume this is related to the disjointness of the classes, which a quick double check has confirmed. Nevertheless, it seems to me to make more sense to reuse properties of classes in other classes if possible instead of redefining them. If this is indeed not possible, I will have to restructure my entire ontology and right now I hope that this is not necessary.
Long story short: Can anyone explain my errors in reasoning?

Thanks in advance,
Vera

Comment: Please provide your minimal complete ontology illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disjoint classes can share object and/or data properties.

You seem to come from a programming object oriented background. In programming classes have attributes (or properties). However, in OWL (the ontology language) properties **do not** belong to classes, but are used to express relations between classes (object properties) or to express relations between classes and data types (data properties). I talk in some detail about the difference between OO and OWL [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/04/15/object-oriented-features-that-owl-lacks/).

There can be many reasons for inconsistencies and without seeing your ontology it is difficult to know their cause exactly. A guess is that you have domain and/or range restrictions on a property that is causing the issue.

Say you have the class `Library` and `Team`, which are disjoint and you have a data property `telephone` and you have defined them as follows:

```
DataProperty: telephone

Class: Library 
   SubClassOf:
       telephone some xsd:string

Class: Team 
   DisjointWith: Library
   SubClassOf:
       telephone some xsd:string
```

This by itself will not cause an inconsistency. However, when you define `telephone` as follows, it will cause an inconsistency:

```
 DataProperty: telephone
   Domain: Library, Team
```

What the `Domain: Library, Team` axiom tells the reasoner is, whenever an individual is linked via `telephone` to another individual, it must infer that the first individual is of type `Library` **and** of type `Team`. Hence the inconsistency.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Remove the `Domain: Library, Team` axiom. This is by far the most common way to deal with it.
2. In some cases I have found it useful to create a `TelephoneDomain` class which is defined to be equivalent to `Library or Team`. Then `telephone` is defined as follows:

   ```
   DataProperty: telephone
     Domain: TelephoneDomain
   ```

The main advantage of having using (a) `Domain: TelephoneDomain` rather than (b)`Domain: Library or Team` is (a) will give me inferences but (b) will not because `Library or Team` is an anonymous class. See my [StackOverflow answer wrt anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69101093/infer-anonymous-class-in-protege-with-the-rules-tab/69101877#69101877).

Comment: Oh my, you nailed it! That's totally it. I made the mistake to think in classes with specific properties instead of properties as semantic link between classes and data types/individuals. Thank you so much for your in depth answer and further links with information! I think I have to overthink my whole concept again (combining bibliographic metadata with phone numbers of team members isn't as easy as I thought haha), but the answer you provided will definetely help, thanks again!

Comment: I am glad it was helpful :-D